# Creating Package Action in OpenWhisk, invocation fails with error message

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm following the example in the documentation for OpenWhisk to create a new Package Action, detailed [here](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions.md#packaging-an-action-as-a-nodejs-module).

Running the `wsk action invoke` step, the platform returns me an invocation error message.

```
[10:57:58 /tmp/workshop]$ wsk action invoke --blocking --result packageAction --param lines '[ "and now", "for something completely", "different" ]'
{
    "error": "Initialization has failed due to: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
      at NodeActionRunner.init (/nodejsAction/runner.js:79:29)
      at doInit (/nodejsAction/src/service.js:134:31)
      at initCode (/nodejsAction/src/service.js:80:24)
      at /nodejsAction/app.js:62:13
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at /nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22\n    at Function.process_params (/nodejsAction/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)"
}
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package Actions is a new feature of the platform.

Ensure you have [upgraded your OpenWhisk CLI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/cli) to the latest version to support this feature. This bug can occur when using an older version of the cli to deploy package actions.

You can verify which version of the CLI you are running with the following command.

```
[14:49:21 /tmp/workshop]$ wsk property get
whisk auth      xxxx:xxx
whisk API host      openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net
whisk API version   v1
whisk namespace     user@host.com
whisk CLI version   2016-10-24T11:55:02+00:00
whisk API build     2016-10-24T12:04:22Z
whisk API build number  whisk-build-1260
```

**Ensure that the CLI version matches or is greater than the version above.**